# Is there a way to upload a text file to Google sheets with delimiters or something to similar to regex to populate the cells

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, automation, data-mining

I'm no expert in google sheets right now. I was wondering if there was a way to upload a text file and populate the cells following a type of regular expression or set of rules to control which data is mined.

Comment: If you file has separators, than you can import it simply through the UI with `File->Import` and specifying the `Separator type` whereby the latter can be `Custom`.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, using App script (javascript), I should be able to open the file using a method. Read the file while a function is run to validate the data demanded. The data is then put into specific cells accordingly.

Comment: Please edit your question if you need to add context - answers are for ....answers.

Comment: It is possible but depends on your file & delimiter hence provide a sample sheet with your problem & what you want to achieve